# PHP multilingual and .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

On my custom CMS I have a page with link like this:

```
www.mywebsite.com/index.php
```

Now I'm trying to use multilingual pages, so I'm testing on the index page. With MySQL and language switcher I'm successfully getting the content from the chosen language.

So, the link becomes like this on English and German:

```
www.mywebsite.com/index.php?lang=en
www.mywebsite.com/index.php?lang=de
```

With this htaccess code I'm removing the .php and index.php:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

So the link becomes like this:

```
www.mywebsite.com/?lang=en
www.mywebsite.com/?lang=de
```

For SEO purpose I want to remove the parameter ?lang=en or ?lang=de and put /en or /de, so the URL to look like this:

```
www.mywebsite.com/en
www.mywebsite.com/de
```

I've tried this with htaccess:

```
RewriteRule ^/(.+?)/(.*)$  $2?lang=$1 [L]
```

or this:

```
RewriteRule ^/(en|de)/(.*)$  $2?lang=$1 [L]
```

But when I try to enter the pages www.mywebsite.com/en or www.mywebsite.com/de, the content doesn't change.

I guess I have a mistake in the htaccess code...

Also I want to do the same functionality on other pages, so let's say this page:

```
www.mywebsite.com/posts?lang=en
```

to become

```
www.mywebsite.com/en/posts
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `$2.php?lang=$1`? Originally you are rewriting to a `.php` file. That is missing in your variants with language.

Comment: HI, ROAL. I've tried that too with this code: **RewriteRule ^/(.+?)/(.*)$  $2.php?lang=$1 [L]**  , but it doesn't change anything.  With this too: **RewriteRule ^/(.+?)/(.*)$  $2?lang=$1 [L]** but its still doesn't work.

Comment: Try to remove the first slash, so it becomes `RewriteRule ^(.+?)/(.*)$ $2.php?lang=$1 [L]`.

Comment: I've tried that too now, but it's still the same.

Comment: After restarting the server, restarting the PHP, it's working! The issue now is when I use your code, it breaks the CSS and JS in the website. I'm searching for solution, if you know, please let me know. BTW you can post your answer, so I can accept and giving you +! Thank you very much.

Comment: Ok, I've found a solution for breaking the CSS and JS. I've just added this lines: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` and `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d` Everything works great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the `.php` in your new rewrite rules.
It should be as follows:

```
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/(.*)$ $2.php?lang=$1 [L]
```

As for the problem mentioned in comments (with CSS and JS files), you've found the correct solution to that, using:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

This tells apache to not apply the RewriteRule if the request is directed to a real existing file or a directory.

Answer (score 0):

To convert `http://example.com/file.php?lang=foo` to `http://example.com/foo/file` you can use the following rules in `root/.htaccesso` :

```
RewriteEngine on

#1)remove .php exten#
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
#2)Redirect "/file.php?lang=foo" to "/foo/file"#
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /([^.]+)\.php\?lang=([^\s&]+)\sHTTP [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%2/%1? [L,R]
#3)The rule bellow will internally map "/foo/file" to "/file.php?lang=foo"#
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(en|de)/([^/]+)/?$ /$2.php?id=$1 [L]
```

[Tested]

Comment: I've pasted exactly your code, cleared the cache and even though  it's not working. If I enter the page `www.mywebsite.com/posts?lang=en` it shows the English content and  `www.mywebsite.com/posts?lang=de` shows the German content, but If I try entering `www.mywebsite.com/en/posts` it still shows the German content, so It doesn't change anything.

Comment: @User2519032 The code works on my server. it looks like there is something else going on. Your php redirects or other htaccess rules might be conflicting with this.